# Thread Matrices, like image channels

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mapthread

The code

```
With[{matA=Partition[Alphabet[],5],matB=Partition[Range@25,5]},

(* matA and matB are 5x5 matrices*)
MapThread[List,{matA,matB},2]

]
```

is fairly straightforward.  The `MapThread` part does 'interleaving' if matA and matB are thought of as image channels.

How do you do this with plain `Thread`?

Comment: **Why** do you want to do it with plain `Thread`? If you already have a solution, can you perhaps explain what problem you are trying to solve that your current solution does not address?

Comment: I wouldn't call `MapThread` overpowered per say, but it seems overly generic.  I don't need to apply an arbitrary function -- I only want to apply List when I have expressions with other Heads to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Thread/@Thread[{matA,matB}]==MapThread[List,{matA,matB},2]
```

Comment: And, of course, `Transpose/@Transpose[{matA,matB}]==MapThread[List,{matA,matB},2]==Transpose/@Thread[{matA,matB}]==Thread/@Transpose[{matA,matB}]`

Answer (score 7):

I personally like using the built in restructuring functions for things like this. Things like ArrayReshape, ArrayPad, Riffle, PadLeft/Right, etc. For this particular case, I think you could use Transpose:

```
Transpose[{Partition[Alphabet[], 5], Partition[Range@25, 5]}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html):

```
matC = Flatten[{matA, matB}, {{2}, {3}}]

MatrixForm[matC, TableDirections -> {Column, Row, Row}]
```

[image]

```
matC == MapThread[List, {matA, matB}, 2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```