# ArrayReshape in an almost rectangular way

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to make a list of many (say 1000) test instances for a geometry problem.  The problem involves two line segments and a point.  So I need

```
{
    (* first line *)     (*second line*)   (*point*)
  { {{x0,y0},{x1,y1}} , {{x2,y2},{x3,y3}} , {x4,y4} },
  ... (*1000 times*)
}
```

Now this is quite easy to achieve with

```
{#[[{1, 2}]], #[[{3, 4}]], #[[5]]} & /@ 
  RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {100, 5, 2}]
```

The `Dimensions` of that desired array are `{1000,3,2}`, which ignores the fact that the lines have extra depth while the point does not.

Is there a way to make this reshaping happen with `ArrayReshape`, or is it for strictly rectangular reshaping?  Is there a clever way to use other functions like `Thread`, `Transpose` etc with their powerful options to do this?

I'll do some benchmarking for curiosity's sake.

---

I recently asked a similar question [Thread Matrices, like image channels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265415/thread-matrices-like-image-channels).  With my wording, the most direct answer (restricted to `Thread`), isn't the best -- it's good to see plenty of votes for all the answers.

Comment: [ArrayReshape >>Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html): _always gives a **rectangular array** of the specified dimensions_

Comment: What would be the correct output of `Dimensions` instead of `{1000,3,2}`?

Comment: That's the correct output of `Dimensions`; I'm not looking for a generalized `Dimensions` function.  I suppose I meant other functions in conjunction with `ArrayReshape`, smarter than simple mapping hacks (i.e. producing 1000 elements of the form `{{{x0,y0},{x1,y1}},{{x2,y2},{x3,y3}},{{x4,y4}}}` and then Mapping to turn the `{{x4,y4}}`'s into `{x4,y4}`'s).

Comment: you might want to try `{{#, #2}, {#3, #4}, #5} & @@@ list` and `Transpose[{#[[All, {1, 2}]], #[[All, {3, 4}]], #[[All, 5]]}] &@list` where `list` is your input  list with dimensions `{100,5,2}`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do something like this:

```
With[
  {n = 1000},
  Transpose[{RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {n, 2, 2}], 
    RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {n, 2, 2}], 
    RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {n, 2}]}]]
```

I don't think there's much savings in overhead by requiring that RandomReal only be called once.

Another approach that overgenerates the original data (but avoids a row-by-row re-partitioning):

```
MapAt[First, RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {1000, 3, 2, 2}], {All, 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright I don't know how to make nice looking plots yet

[image: plot]

but kglr's approach

```
Transpose[{#[[All, {1, 2}]], #[[All, {3, 4}]], #[[All, 5]]}] &@list
```

and lecicr's first approach that calls `RandomReal` three times are both fastest, presumably by a constant factor by the looks of it.

---

The big takeaway for me is that calling `RandomReal` three times instead of once is a tiny performance hit.  The following code could be fleshed out into a super informative test, but here it is for now

```
dat = Table[With[{sampleparts = Differences@Round[Range[0, m] n/m]},
SeedRandom@102;
First@AbsoluteTiming[RandomReal[{-100, 100}, #] & /@ sampleparts]
], {n, 1, 500}, {m, 1, n}];
```

It divides `n` into `m` approximately equal sized chunks (e.g. 47=4+3+4+3+4+4+3+4+4+3+4+3+4) and then calls `RandomReal` to generate the total amount of numbers in all the different sizes of chunks (all in 1 chunk, 2 chunks, 3 chunks... up to n chunks of size 1).  Then the code

```
ListPlot3D[PadRight[#, 500] & /@ dat, 
AxesLabel -> {"m roughly uniform chunks", "n total random numbers", 
"total time"}]
```

yields
[image: randomtimingplot]

You can see that around m=100 chunks there's a huge jump.  Seeing this sort of plot for large numbers on a logloglog scale would be cool.

Comment: Since the performance of random functions isn't exactly on topic, lmk if I should ask a new question and move some stuff, or if there's a trickier way to migrate info somehow.

Comment: If you call `RandomReal` once, you get a packed array that has to be unpacked since your desired data structure is not rectangular. So any savings in the single call takes hit in restructuring the data. Both the savings and the hits are probably small on data this size. As for the jump, I believe `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength"]` explains it. It has nothing to do with `RandomReal`, I believe. (`SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]` shows other such boundaries as well.)

Comment: See for instance [(54994)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54994), [(55242)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55242)

Comment: So then kglr's approach with `[[All...]]` also avoids unpacking/restructuring?

Comment: Also that comment deserves +100.  What other programming language (community) makes these intricate behaviors so transparent!!

Comment: Yes, `list[[All, {1,2}]]` avoids unpacking, but `Transpose` in that [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265514/arrayreshape-in-an-almost-rectangular-way/265566?noredirect=1#comment661746_265514) will unpack the arrays because the result is not rectangular. If you think about it, your ultimate output is a list of geometric primitives, and at some point the data has to be copied out of a packed array. I also wonder if it's worth worrying about performance too much for only 1000 instances. (And thanks for the compliment!)